# React Bootstrap Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a navigation but activeKey sticks with the value "1". And I couldn't use the 'to' property of React.

```
constructor(state) {
    super(state);
    this.state = {
        activeKey: 1
    };
}

handleSelect(eventKey) {
    this.setState({
        activeKey: eventKey
    })
}

<Nav variant="pills" activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
 onSelect={() => this.handleSelect(this)}>

     <NavItem>
            <NavLink exact eventKey="1" href="/">Home</NavLink>
     </NavItem>

</Nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the active event key to the `onSelect` callback.

```
onSelect={key => this.handleSelect(key)}
```

or

```
onSelect={this.handleSelect}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't notice I didn't pass the key in the function. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use to="/something" you need to wrap your NavLink with a LinkContainer component from https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Comment: This solution will solve your note, whereas drew's should remedy the activeKey problem